# Clearcase client installation issue- Linux RHEL5

Tags: linux, clearcase, rhel5, clearcase-remote-client

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask this question. I have been trying to install clearcase client 8015 on a new machine with RHEL5u8 image. Tried googling a lot but could not resolve the issue as per suggestions on other forums.

1. It gets installed **successfully**. (As per the prompt)
2. listing of the views is done properly. (**cleartool lsview**)
3. When I do **cleartool mount -all,**

> cleartool: Error: The MVFS file system is not installed or not loaded,
>   or the 'viewroot' is not mounted or is inaccessible: not a ClearCase
>   object.

4. logging in as root then starting clearcase, executing **"/opt/rational/clearcase/etc/clearcase start"**
   OUTPUT:-

> ClearCase is stopped Starting ClearCase ClearCase daemons: albd_server
>   FATAL: Error inserting mvfs
>   (/lib/modules/2.6.18-308.4.1.0.1.el5/kernel/fs/mvfs/mvfs.ko): Unknown
>   symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg) Loading the MVFS
>   was unsuccessful(8:1) /opt/rational/clearcase/etc/clearcase: Loading
>   MVFS failed
>   ---- Please review /var/log/messages for information on the problem.
>   ---- You may need to rebuild your kernel, rebuild your mvfs module,
>   ---- and reboot your system. Information on how to do this can be found in
>   ---- your Release Notes and file /var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/README.txt.

I have followed all the steps in /var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/README.txt but still cannot achieve anything.

**Uninstallation also fails as:-**
./linux_8015_uninstall

> ERROR: Installation data has incompatible version 1.8.0; expected
>   1.7.0. Newer version of the Installation Manager was used on this system.
>
> java.io.IOException: Installation data has incompatible version 1.8.0;
>   expected 1.7.0. Newer version of the Installation Manager was used on
>   this system.
>
> 00:01.33 ERROR [main]
>   com.ibm.cic.agent.core.application.HeadlessApplication run
>   Installation data has incompatible version 1.8.0; expected 1.7.0.
>   Newer version of the Installation Manager was used on this system.
>   java.io.IOException: Installation data has incompatible version 1.8.0;
>   expected 1.7.0. Newer version of the Installation Manager was used on
>   this system.   java.io.IOException: Installation data has incompatible
>   version 1.8.0; expected 1.7.0. Newer version of the Installation
>   Manager was used on this system.
>       at com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.core.InstallRegistryParser.parse(InstallRegistryParser.java:160)
>       at com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.core.InstallRegistry.load(InstallRegistry.java:679)
>       at com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.core.InstallRegistry.openFile(InstallRegistry.java:485)
>       at com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.core.InstallRegistry.open(InstallRegistry.java:429)

Cannot proceed with installation, cannot uninstall either to try another version of clearcase, tried googling for the version mismatch of IBM installation manager but could not find anything addressing the issue properly for Linux.
Any suggestions on how to proceed? I am new to clearcase tool.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I see only snapshot views are supported, and MVFS (for dynamic views) hasn't installed properly, I uninstall everything and try the all process from the start again.

In your case, that means installing or downgrading the [IBM IM Installation Manager to the right version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142) ([similar to this issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21973166)).
It can be an [IM update issue, as seen  in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21439108).

Answer (score 0):

Further to @VonC's comment re: incompatible IM install,
review the following doc: [MVFS not loading after kernel upgrade or is missing after installation on Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577253).
I encountered a similar problem after an incompatible kernel path / ClearCase version. In my case, the error was similar to what is documented here in the post  [MVFS not installed - RHEL6](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c6de1c66-b35f-4412-bb8d-93585bdff215)  and I had to edit the kernel source to the same as the patch and rebuild. Then things stared up fine.

Review also the link [How to manually restore a pre-built MVFS on Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577259).

If the corresponding kerenl level is not provided it will not start and you will have to patch and make your own.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I tried this already, it mitigates some issues, but still I think mounting of vob directories is an issue. I can see vob mounted properly but when I do "cd /vobs/product" it hangs. I will reimage and try some lower version of clearcase.

Comment: Are you sure it's hung? I discovered a bug (on AIX 6.1 + CC8.0.0) where app appeared hung when creating baseline from GUI when in fact there was a background process waiting for user input (hint: never gonna get it). Also found a performance issue where any cmd performed within a dyn view caused a scan of every vob, sometimes taking > 5 mins just to `cd` or `pwd`. Try using [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to confirm it's hung and where/why. Have you considered moving up from RHEL5 ?